# Split string using elements of array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello i'm working on dynamic search for my first web application
and i have a huge problem i've been working on this for several hours using diffrent solutions in the end i think this might be the closest to resolving my problems.

Search is not static so hard coding this is not an option.

```js
const search = 'someone loves some thing';
const teams = ['some thing', 'someone', 'help'];
const twoTeams = [];

if (teams.some(el => search.includes(el))) {
  teams.forEach(word => {
    if (search.includes(word)) {
      twoTeams.push(word);
    }
  })
}
console.log(twoTeams); // ['some thing','someone']
console.log(search) // 'someone loves some thing'
// looking for // console.log(twoTeams)// 'someone','some thing'
```

And here im stuck i have array of items that i need to split string with to access data from API i just need it in that order i cant reverse order because in the app theres too many elements in array and user can search anything so you dont know which one should will be index[0] and which one should be index[1] and thats crucial to my dynamic search.

Comment: so what is your desired output?

Comment: @KarlL im looking for if search is 'someone loves some thing' output has to be : 'someone','some thing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd start with removing the outer `if` as we check every word anyway in the inner condition.

```js
teams.forEach(word => {
    // Get the position of word in the search text. Negative value means that there is no match.
    let index = search.indexOf(word);

    // If the search text contains the word
    if (index >= 0) {
        // Save both the matching word and its index
        twoTeams.push( { 'word': word, 'index': index});
    }
})

// Sort the results by the index and select the word only
twoTeams = results.sort((a,b)=> a.index - b.index).map(result => result.word);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, been working on this for 9 hours i had no idea that sort method exist, your answer was incredibly helpful.

Comment: This answer would be more efficient than mine. It would `find` in `search` only `once`. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to built `twoTeams` object with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like below.

```
const twoTeams = teams.filter(el => search.includes(el));
```

As you want preserve order then you can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your results with `indexOf` like below.

```
twoTeams.sort((a, b) => search.indexOf(a) - search.indexOf(b));
```

Try it below.

```js
const search = 'someone loves some thing';
const teams = ['some thing', 'someone', 'help'];
const twoTeams = teams.filter(el => search.includes(el));
twoTeams.sort((a, b) => search.indexOf(a) - search.indexOf(b));

console.log(twoTeams); // looking for ['someone', 'some thing']
console.log(search) // 'someone loves some thing'
```

Comment: Yeah, i overcomplicated that a bit :D, lost track after several hour's this is a great and clever answer. It's just mad that that i spend whole night trying to resolve this and i was 4 lines of code. Thank you for help !!!